# Ошибка при шифровании TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Tags: python, web3.py

Написал вот такой вот код

```
from web3 import Web3
import uuid

I = uuid.UUID(input())

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://sokol.poa.network'))
print(w3.soliditySha3(['uint128'], I.int))
```

Он должен шифровать идентификатор вида a52b5033-35d1-4aa6-8190-72f0116edba3 по алгоритму keccak256. Но при выполнении выдает такую ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не работал с этой библиотекой, но судя по примерам в документации, функция soliditySha3 ожидает в качестве обоих аргументов списки.

Возможно, вам нужно вызывать её как-то так:

```
print(w3.soliditySha3(['uint128'], [I.int]))
```

Comment: я дурачок начинающий, да просят меня все боги))))))